# Find inside a list a point that is closest to another point

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

**Introduction**

Say you want to determine which point inside a list is the closest to another given point. A function should return the point itself and the distance as well.

E.g with this data:

```
(def pts [[2 4] [1 9] [9 4] [2 8]])
(def p [7 6])
```

First of all, some helper functions are needed:

```
(def abs js/Math.abs)
(def pow js/Math.pow)
(def sqrt js/Math.sqrt)
(def pow2 #(pow % 2))

(defn distance [p1 p2]
  (sqrt (+ (pow2 (abs (- (p1 0) (p2 0))))
           (pow2 (abs (- (p1 1) (p2 1)))))))
```

---

**Two proposals**

My first approach was the following:

```
(defn find-closest [p pts]
  (->> (map #(vector (distance p %) %) pts)
       (reduce (fn [m v]
                 (if (< (v 0) (m 0))
                   v
                   m)))))

(find-closest p pts)
=> [2.8284271247461903 [9 4]] ;; this is a correct result
```

By trying to make the function more perfomant I came up with this second version:

```
(defn find-closest2 [p pts]
  (let [init (first pts)]
    (reduce (fn [m v]
              (let [d (distance p v)]
                (if (< d (m 0))
                  [d v]
                  m)))
            [(distance p init) init]
            (rest pts))))
```

And indeed, the later function turned out to be quite faster (tested in chromium-browser 49):

```
=> (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (find-closest p pts)))
"Elapsed time: 445.720000 msecs"
=> (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (find-closest2 p pts)))
"Elapsed time: 248.900000 msecs"
```

A note aside: Does anybody have a hint, why the same functions were way slower in Clojure:?

```
user> (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (find-closest p pts)))
"Elapsed time: 6886.850965 msecs"                                                                                                                              
user> (time (dotimes [_ 100000] (find-closest2 p pts)))
"Elapsed time: 6574.486679 msecs"
```

This would be more than 10 times slower, which I find hard to believe.

**Question**

Anyways, since I need the functions for a ClojureScript project, here is my question: How would you approach this problem? `find-closest` looks ok to me, however the faster version `find-closest2` looks a bit confusing. Is there maybe a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As with all cases where you make decisions based on micro-benchmarks it's worth using a benchmarking library such as [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium/) to make sure you are seeing a statistically significant result.

In this case the difference lies in **computing intermediate lazy sequences that are immediately thrown away**. `map` is producing a sequence of all the potential answers, and allocating memory for each. Since you are not interested in using the intermediary result this time is wasted and your reduce only version is faster.

Until recently Clojure programs had to sometimes choose between being simple and composible using map reduce filter etc, and being fast by not producing intermediate results. **This was fixed with [trannsducers](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers)** so now you can use the map version without introducing intermediate results, and you can do it in a very general and adaptable way.

```
user> (import '[java.lang.Math])
nil
user> (def pow2 #(Math/pow % 2))
      (defn distance [p1 p2]
       (Math/sqrt (+ (pow2 (Math/abs (- (p1 0) (p2 0))))
                  (pow2 (Math/abs (- (p1 1) (p2 1)))))))
#'user/pow2
#'user/distance
user> (defn closer-point
        ([] [Long/MAX_VALUE [Long/MAX_VALUE Long/MAX_VALUE]])
        ([p1] p1)
        ([[distance1 point1 :as p1]
          [distance2 point2 :as p2]]
         (if (< distance1 distance2)
           p1
           p2)))
#'user/closer-point
user> (transduce (map #(vector (distance p %) %))
                 closer-point
                 pts)
[2.8284271247461903 [9 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `min-key` function is designed for just this problem. Here is the JVM version.  Note that we simply minimize the squared distance and don't bother computing the actual distance with `Math/sqrt`:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [clojure.core       :as clj]
            [schema.core        :as s]
            [tupelo.types       :as tt]
            [tupelo.schema      :as ts]
            [criterium.core     :as crit]
  ))

; Prismatic Schema type definitions
(s/set-fn-validation! true)   ; #todo add to Schema docs

(def pts [[2 4] [1 9] [9 4] [2 8]])
(def p [7 6])

(defn square [x] (* x x))

(defn dist2 [p1 p2]
  (+ (square (- (p1 0) (p2 0)))
     (square (- (p1 1) (p2 1)))))

(doseq [curr-p pts]
  (println "curr-p: " curr-p " -> " (dist2 p curr-p)))

(newline)
(spyx (apply min-key #(dist2 p %) pts))

(newline)
(crit/quick-bench (apply min-key #(dist2 p %) pts))

(defn -main [] )
```

I would not worry too much about premature optimization of the code, just make it simple and understandable first.  Using a built-in function is nearly always a good start for that (as is the old trick of just minimizing the square of a quantity when you don't really need the square-root). Notice that I also got rid of the `(abs ...)` call since the `(square ...)` does that automatically.

Here are the results of the run:

```
curr-p:  [2 4]  ->  29
curr-p:  [1 9]  ->  45
curr-p:  [9 4]  ->  8
curr-p:  [2 8]  ->  29

(apply min-key (fn* [p1__8701#] (dist2 p p1__8701#)) pts) => [9 4]

WARNING: Final GC required 7.5524163302816705 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 1132842 in 6 samples of 188807 calls.
             Execution time mean : 527.711887 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 3.437558 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 524.840276 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 531.911280 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.534138 ns
```